# Google Cloud Run - how to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-run

I'm setting up my first application on Google Cloud Run and now want to connect the server with my website. However I've run into CORS issues.

I tried fixing it in my code by using flask_cors. I can see on my requests coming from localhost that they do include the CORS headers, but it doesn't from Cloud Run.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

I've also tried setting CORS on the buckets it's using behind the scenes. Used the following code

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://
```

Link: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

I expected to find instructions on how to set CORS on Cloud Run somewhere, but haven't been able to find any. I tried making my container/API support CORS, but when I push it to Cloud Run it "goes away".

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean when you push the flask_cors app to Cloud Run and send an OPTION request to the Cloud Run service, CORS headers are missing in the response?

Comment: I'm not sure why GCS is relevant here. If you need to make your GCS buckets served as a website, you can do that without Cloud Run.

Comment: Can you share the output from curl, or whatever application you're using to inspect the headers when making a request to Cloud Run?

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the Cloud Run python sample like you described

```py
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, world!\n'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

I am able to get `access-control-allow-origin: *` header both locally and remotely on Cloud Run.

```
docker run --rm -i -e PORT=8080 -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/ahmetb-samples-playground/run/cors-test
```

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 18:23:06 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 14
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Cloud Run:

```
$ curl -v https://cors-test-dpyb4duzqq-uc.a.run.app
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< x-cloud-trace-context: 8503b029795fdc57bbc4267961806847;o=1
< date: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 18:23:30 GMT
< server: Google Frontend
< content-length: 14
```

Both responses carry the `access-control-allow-origin` header set in your application. Cloud Run doesn't strip off this header.

I'm not sure how/why GCS CORS permissions are relevant to this question. If you want to serve websites directly from GCS Buckets, read [Hosting a static Website on GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

If you’re just proxying the request from Cloud Run to GCS, yes, it might be inheriting the CORS headers from the GCS response. I recommend you inspect those headers.

Comment: I can second this, I am also unable to reproduce the "missing headers" behavior. Perhaps OP's issue is the difference between the casing of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `access-control-allow-origin`?

Comment: Yeah, they're the same header and should not be treated differently.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google Thanks for answering. My skills with webdevelopment are limited, as I work as a data scientist. After I added this above each endpoint it worked like a charm (I don't know why though). `@cross_origin(origin=['localhost'], headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'])`

Comment: Also maybe I should note that i'm not trying to host a website, but actually run a machine learning model. (it's very small, so I don't need it to be very quick). So I'm trying to use it as a FaaS, but smartere (which is what I hoped is what it was intended for)